# Visualforce remote objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript-remoting

I was reading through this documentation.

http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_vf_remote_objects.htm

As per the doc:

> Visualforce Remote Objects are proxy objects that allow **basic DML
>   operations on sObjects directly from JavaScript**

Does this mean that any org that do not have API/ Apex class access (like professional org:I  assume all orgs have VF page access but restricted with APEX/ API access) can start using VF page/ with Visualforce remote objects for doing DML operations ?

> Notice something very unusual about this page—**there is no controller
>   or controller extension**. All of the data access is handled by the
>   Remote Objects components.
>
> Like JavaScript remoting, Remote Objects calls **don’t count towards API
>   request limits**.

Looking more, this feature seems awesome that you use JS with VF and start CRUDing Sobjects

http://www.oyecode.com/2014/02/how-to-use-salesforce-remote-objects-in.html

> Some cool features this offers over JavaScript remoting are :
>
> 1. Freedom from controllers
> 2. No Test classes
> 3. Easy code management
> 4. Not counted against API call

please clarify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Apex Developer’s Guide has a section [Best Practices for Using Remote Objects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_remote_objects_considerations.htm) that  is very well written and, generally, addresses what Remote Objects are good for and what they aren’t.  Here is the first sentence on the page:

> Visualforce Remote Objects is an effective tool for quickly adding simple data operations to Visualforce pages.

The page then goes on to cover limitations with transaction boundaries (e.g., inserting an Order and Order Products in one transaction isn’t possible), addresses issues on business logic placement, handling complexity, and gives alternatives to Remote Objects.

The short answer is simple CRUD based functionality is where Remote Objects work best.  For example, an app that lets you edit Contact information, or an app that displays a List of some Object, etc., are good. A complex financial system, probably not a good fit.

Know that there are [documented limitations](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_remote_objects_limitations.htm).  It is still in developer preview so is subject to change without backward compatibility and it is also documented as not yet feature complete.

Can it be used in PE?
I didn’t see it documented anywhere that they can’t be used in a PE org.  I just signed up for a Professional Edition Pre-release on [the pre-release sign up page](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-spring14.jsp) and was able to use Remote Objects without issue.

Comment: just FYI, looks like Best Practices goes to a dead link

Comment: @MattBaker - Thanks. Had a trailing period in the link. Should work now.

Comment: I love the addition of the best practices topic in the Salesforce documentation, a key thing to keep in mind is the section on Transaction Boundaries, please take time to fully understand what is being said, as regards data integrity, in this section and the implications on your use or not as the case maybe of this feature.